# FileReader - How to change the character encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to upload files to **Google Drive through the API** provided for the product. However, I think there is a problem with the encoding - in particular, the `FileReader.readAsText()` function.

I tried adding the optional parameter for encoding to make it look like `r.readAsText(f,'ANSI')` but it seems to not work.

The `readAsText()` *function defaults to UTF-8 encoding for some weird reason*. When I try to upload image files with UTF-8 encoding, they're corrupted and do not open properly.

```
 function readFile(evt) {
            var fData = [];
            var f = evt.target.files[0];
            if (f) {
                var r = new FileReader();
                r.readAsText(f);
                fData.unshift(f.name, f.type);
                var myInt = setInterval(function() {
                    if (r.readyState == 2) {
                        fData.push(r.result);
                        uploadFiles(fData);
                        clearInterval(myInt);
                    }
                }, 50);
            } else {
                alert("Failed to load file");
            }

        }


        function uploadFiles(dataArray,callback) {
                const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
                const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
                const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

                const contentType = 'application/json';

                var metadata = {
                    'name': dataArray[0],
                    'mimeType': dataArray[1]
                };

                var multipartRequestBody =
                    delimiter +
                    'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
                    JSON.stringify(metadata) +
                    delimiter +
                    'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n\r\n' +
                    dataArray[2] +
                    close_delim;

                var request = gapi.client.request({
                    'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files',
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'params': { 'uploadType': 'multipart' },
                    'headers': {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                    },
                    'body': multipartRequestBody
                });
                if (!callback) {
                    callback = function(file) {
                        console.log(file)
                    };
                }
                request.execute(callback);
        }

        document.getElementById('upFile').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to upload files to Google Drive using Drive API by JavaScript. How about this workaround? In this workaround, the file is converted to base64 and uploaded to Google Drive.

#### Modification points :

- Use `readAsDataURL()` instead of `readAsText()`.
- Define data as base64 in request body.

#### Modified script :

Please modify 2 parts as follows.

1. From :

```
r.readAsText(f);
```

1. To :

```
r.readAsDataURL(f);
```

2. From :

```
var multipartRequestBody =
    delimiter +
    'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
    JSON.stringify(metadata) +
    delimiter +
    'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n\r\n' +
    dataArray[2] +
    close_delim
```

2. To :

```
var multipartRequestBody =
    delimiter +
    'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
    JSON.stringify(metadata) +
    delimiter +
    'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' + // Modified
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n' + // Added
    dataArray[2].split(",")[1] + // // Modified
    close_delim
```

#### Reference :

- [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Also I have experienced the same situation with you. At that time, I resolved this using base64.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, this worked. I tried with readAsDataURL() before but I think what really makes it work in the end is **Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 header**.

Comment: @TKD21 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. Yes. I had also had the issue about the same situation with you before. So I could remember this solution when I saw your issue. Thank you, too.